# Is this twin prime-related sequence known?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, factorial, twin-primes

For a positive integer $\ m\ $ define $\ k_m\ $ to be the smallest positive integer such that $$k_m\cdot m!\pm 1$$ form a twin-prime pair.

> Has the sequence $(k_m)$ already been verified ?

The first $\ 30\ $ entries of the sequence are :

```
[4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 17, 7, 6, 3, 14, 29, 30, 48, 27, 9, 24, 12, 97, 78, 47, 71, 80, 55, 13, 57, 20, 81, 259, 108, 163]
```

I am particular interested in $\ k_{2022}\ $

UPDATE : hardmath found the twin prime $$1892020\cdot 2022!\pm 1$$ so we have $$k_{2022}\le 1\ 892\ 020$$

Comment: OEIS A071406 https://oeis.org/search?q=4%2C+2%2C+1%2C+3%2C+2%2C+17%2C+7%2C+6%2C+3%2C+14%2C+29%2C+30%2C+48%2C+27%2C+9%2C+24%2C+12%2C+97%2C+78+&sort=&language=english&go=Search

Comment: You should know about OEIS by now and should have checked there first.  Also, you should be more careful of typos.  $k\cdot m!\pm 1$ does not have $k_m$ appearing in the expression, but it does have $k$ which you have not defined yet.  Surely, you mean $k_m\cdot m!\pm 1$.

Comment: I'm actually a little bit surprised that this sequence is in the OEIS, when I saw the question my reaction was closer to "why would anyone ever consider that?".

Comment: @CaptainLama:  The cases $k=1$ have a long history going back e.g. to Euclid.  More information in [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2002-71-237/S0025-5718-01-01315-1/S0025-5718-01-01315-1.pdf) by Caldwell and Gallot.

Comment: Regarding $k_{2022}$:  what have you tried?  Have you done a search with (e.g.) OpenPFGW?

Comment: @RaviFernando According to my calculations, no $k\le 2\cdot 10^5$ does the job , doublechecks are of course welcome ! In fact, I used PFGW.

Comment: According to hardmath, we have $$k_{2022}=1\ 892\ 020$$